# How to disable logs grouping in Sentry?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sentry

I am using Spring Boot and Sentry to log info/warn/error logs from the app.

My `application.properties`:

```
sentry.dsn=<DNS_URL>
sentry.in-app-includes=com.github.chameleontartu.example
sentry.logging.enabled=true
sentry.send-default-pii=true
sentry.logging.minimum-event-level=info
sentry.use-git-commit-id-as-release=true
```

The issue is that all logs got grouped by the process id, and I cannot see what causes what actions. The same type of errors are also got stacked, so I can't find the latest one.

How can I change settings in Senty.io or Spring Boot app properties to see each log entry separately and disable grouping of the same logs?

I checked Sentry docs but cannot understand how to alter current behavior.

Comment: Grouping is based on the log template (uninterpolated message) unless there's a a stacktrace. You can turn stacktraces for all eventts withs: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/configuration/options/#attach-stacktrace this should help with grouping by code location (where you call logger.log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Bruno Garcia, in the properties file, you can specify in the resources `application.properties`:

```
sentry.attach-stacktrace=true
```

Logs are appearing one by one, and it is easier to follow them up. All the related context is attached to the log messages themselves.